# Accusing for sex offenders

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, sexual-offences

Can someone register your phone number in a sex offenders list without no proof is this illegal because I’m trying to sue them

Comment: This is too vague. You need to provide a lot more details. Exactly which list are you talking about, who runs it, how do you know about this, and any other details. Tell us what happened, one thing at a time, in the order they happened. It may just be a crude spam blackmail  attempt, or something else. Also what US state are you in?

Comment: I don't see that this in any way asks for specific legal advice, and in my view this should not be closed for that reason. But I do think more detail is needed to give a quality answer.

Comment: You almost certainly have to name the county and state, but usually you have to go through the sheriff's office and provide more than just a phone number. That is for *official* mandatory registration. Anybody who knows how can set up a defamatory website that collects names or phone numbers, and you'd have to sue them.

Answer (score 2):

The various government-run lists of sex offenders generally allow listing only of those who have actually been convicted of, or pled guilty to, crimes considered to be sex offenses. Beyond that there is no way to answer without additional information.